# Not uniform axes thickness in the plot

Tags: plotting

I am using Mathematica to prepare figures for a paper. I found that the thickness of the frame axes can easily become not uniform. For example, when I changed the frame thickness using 
`plot = ListPlot[data, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]]]`
The figure looks like this:
[image]
The right-hand side axis is much thicker than the top axis.

And when I try to raster the image to a larger size using the following code, the not uniform axes thickness rises again: 
code: `plot = ListPlot[data, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]]];
Rasterize[plot, RasterSize -> 600]`

The plot looks like this:
[image]

Again, the right-hand side axis is thicker.

Can someone help me to solve this problem? What I need is a rasterized plot with uniformly thicker axes.

Comment: Use `Rasterize[plot, RasterSize -> 600, ImageResolution -> 200, 
 ImageSize -> 600]`